# Lilypond paper settings

Tags: lilypond

I want to incorporate Lilypond generated PDFs into a book. I would like to have two sided PDFs. I referred here: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/horizontal-spacing-paper-variables. But can't quite figure out what is the correct syntax. This is what I tried so far:

```
\paper {                                                                         
  two-sided = true                                                               
  inner-margin = 0.75\in                                                         
  outer-margin = 0.25\in                                                         
  system-system-spacing =                                                        
    #'((basic-distance . 18)                                                     
       (minimum-distance . 8)                                                    
       (padding . 1)                                                             
       (stretchability . 60))                                                    
  }
```

How do I specify 0.75 in as inner margin and 0.25 in as outer margin? The above code does not give an error but does not make any difference to the output either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `two-sided = true` you should do `two-sided = ##t`. `#t` and `#true` are the scheme names for the boolean true, and you need an additional `#` to tell Lilypond to parse this a scheme expression.